# Parsing with XPath a xml document. Why add a <xml tag as a header> in the result?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I searched on google first and I found many result about how to parse with xpath a xml document. I have parse it but a want to convert a NODELIST in String and I have created a method for it:

```
private String processResult(Document responseDocument) throws XPathExpressionException,       TransformerException {
   NodeList soaphead = responseDocument.getElementsByTagName("xmlTagToTrasform"); 
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
   Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 
   serializer.transform(new DOMSource(soaphead.item(0)), new StreamResult(sw)); 
   String result = sw.toString();
   return result;
}
```

This method works perfectly but the transformer adds an `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in the header of the result, and I don't want that. This is the result of the method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlTagToTrasform>
  <xmlTagToTrasform2>
        .
        .
        .
        .
  </xmlTagToTrasform2>
</xmlTagToTrasform>
```

Comment: Solutions in xpath are welcome! I have an xml doc, i want to extract only a content of that tag with all the tag inside it. I try with no result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure the transformer not to output the XML declaration, before you call `transform`:

```
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

Answer (score -3):

XML is a markup language and every xml document has this line on the top to specify the version and the encoding-type. It is madatory to have this.

Comment: No, it's absolutely *not* mandatory. It's valid to have a document with no document declaration.

Comment: How i can remove that without using a string parsing?

Comment: No it's not mandatory, read the spec. prolog is mandatory `prolog    ::=    XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?` but all its parts are optional